# Redirection conflict in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We want to redirect the blog folder to the news folder. For example: Anyone visiting ...

- `https://example.com/blog/blog-title` redirect to `https://example.com/news/blog-title`
- `https://example.com/news-blog-presenters` redirect to `https://example.com/blog`.

Below is my HTACCESS code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news-blog-speaker/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/?$ /news/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news-blog-speaker/?$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^/blog/?$ /news/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

There are a few issues with the above directive:

- In `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. So, it should be `^blog`, not `^/blog`.
- You are only attempting to match `/blog` or `/blog/`. But you need to redirect `/blog/<blog-title>` - as stated in your question description.
- Since you are not capturing anything in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, the `$1` backreference is always empty. You need to capture `<blog-title>` from the requested URL, but as mentioned above, you have made no attempt to do this.
- The preceding condition (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks the request is not `/news-blog-speaker` is entirely superfluous, since you are already checking that the request is `/blog`. It can't be both.
- Take note of the WordPress *comment*. You should not be manually editing the code between the `# BEGIN/END WordPress` comment markers.

Try the following instead *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section:

```
# Redirect "/blog/<blog-title>" to "/news/<blog-title>"
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/?$ /news/$1 [R=302,L]

# Redirect "/news-blog-presenters" to "/blog"
RewriteRule ^news-blog-presenters/?$ /blog [R=302,L]
```

The "conflict" is avoided by matching a non-empty `<blog-title>` and not simply `/blog/`. This seems to be what you require based on your stated requirements.

I assume `/blog` is not a physical directory, otherwise a request for `/blog` (no trailing slash) will trigger a redirect to `/blog/` (by mod_dir).

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to a 301 (permanent) - if that is required - after you have confirmed the redirect works as intended.

You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: # Redirect "/blog/<blog-title>" to "/news/<blog-title>"
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)$ /news/$1 [R=302,L] 

This part didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work" exactly? Do you get an error? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? What is the actual URL you are requesting?

Comment: Thanks, I had to amend your code and add a trailing slash in the end.

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/$ /news/$1 [R=302,L]

Comment: Ok, but the example URL you stated in your question did not include a trailing slash. I've updated my answer to make the trailing slash _optional_. Note, however, that this trailing slash is omitted from the redirected URL.